# MonthOf TDateTime ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++builder, tdatetime

I am using `C++ Builder` and am creating a GUI application using the `TDateTime` data type.

When I use the `MonthOf()` method on a `TDateTime` object, I am getting a value that is 1 month behind from the actual month of the `TDateTime` object.

Why is this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you write an example with, say, the TDateTime value (numeric and in text) and what you expect MonthOf to give, and what it actually gives?  [MonthOf is supposed to return a value between 1 and 12](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DateUtils.MonthOf), so if you're assuming it's 0-based you will need to account for a difference of 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get current month try this code:

```
TDateTime dt = Now();
CurMonth=StrToInt(FormatDateTime("mm", dt));
```

Comment: That's a bit overkill. You could just use `DecodeDate()` instead.